# MongoDB MapReduce strange value when reduce function does not use variable from emit

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I want to use mapreduce to perform the group aggregation. 
Here is my map function :

```
function() {
     emit(this.TransactionType, { Count: 1 });
}
```

Here is two reduce functions :

```
function(key, values) {
    var result = {Count: 0};
    values.forEach(function(value) {
        result.Count += 1; 
    });
    return result;
}

function(key, values) {
    var result = {Count: 0};
    values.forEach(function(value) {
        result.Count += value.Count; 
    });
    return result;
}
```

and here is the two results :

```
"_id" : "A", "value" : { "Count" : 13.0 }  
"_id" : "B", "value" : { "Count" : 2.0 }  
"_id" : "C", "value" : { "Count" : 1.0 }  
"_id" : "D", "value" : { "Count" : 209.0 }  
"_id" : "E", "value" : { "Count" : 66.0 }  
"_id" : "F", "value" : { "Count" : 11.0 }  
"_id" : "G", "value" : { "Count" : 17.0 }  
"_id" : "H", "value" : { "Count" : 17.0 } 


"_id" : "A", "value" : { "Count" : 128.0 } 
"_id" : "B", "value" : { "Count" : 115.0 } 
"_id" : "C", "value" : { "Count" : 1.0 } 
"_id" : "D", "value" : { "Count" : 3645.0 } 
"_id" : "E", "value" : { "Count" : 1405.0 } 
"_id" : "F", "value" : { "Count" : 256.0 } 
"_id" : "G", "value" : { "Count" : 380.0 } 
"_id" : "H", "value" : { "Count" : 398.0 }
```

So why the two results are different?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's helpful to think of the "reduce" function in terms of the ["fold" higher-order function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29).  That is to say, your "reduce" function will be applied to a list of values and an *accumulated* object (the "result" variable in your examples), which is initially specified but will eventually be replaced by the *output of successive calls to your function*.  More over, the list of values to which your function will be applied can be broken up into any number of sub-lists, in any order!

For example, consider how your function would behave using the [JavaScript Array "reduce" function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), which is an example of the "fold" higher-order function.  Your first example will behave improperly because it doesn't use the "Count" property of each element.  Successive attempts to use it with Array#reduce will fail similarly:

```javascript
function badReducer(accum, x) {
  accum.Count += 1;
  return accum;
}
var sum = {Count:0};
sum = [{Count:1}, {Count:2}, {Count:3}].reduce(badReducer, sum);
sum; // => {Count:3}, d'oh!
sum = [{Count:4}].reduce(badReducer, sum);
sum; // => {Count:5}, d'oh!
```

However, your second example properly adds the "Count" property and can be applied successively to its own output:

```javascript
function goodReducer(accum, x) {
  accum.Count += x.Count;
  return accum;
}
var sum = {Count:0};
sum = [{Count:1}, {Count:2}, {Count:3}].reduce(goodReducer, sum);
sum; // => {Count:6}, woohoo!
sum = [{Count:4}].reduce(goodReducer, sum);
sum; // => {Count:10}, woohoo!
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't read the http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-ReduceFunction carefully

Answer (score 1):

The first reduce function does this for each value:

```
result.Count += 1;
```

The second one does this:

```
result.Count += value.Count;
```

So, if your values list is `(1,2,3,4,5)`, the first one would add +1 for each item and will return 5 as the output. The second one will add +5 for each item (because value.Count is 5), and so it will output 5+5+5+5+5=25

Answer (score 1):

The reduce function must be written such that it may be re-run several times, using its own output as the new input.

The result function outputs data in the form of {_id, [values]}.  For your reduce function, the input could be the following:

```
"A", [{count:1}, {count:2}, {count:3}]
```

In the first function, count will only incremented by 1 for each document in the values array, and the output will be:

```
"A", {count:3}
```

in the second function, the values of count will be added, so the output will be

```
"A", {count:6}
```

This is what you are experiencing.  For a step-by-step walkthrough of how a Map Reduce operation is run, please see the "Extras" section of the MongoDB Cookbook recipe "Finding Max And Min Values with Versioned Documents" http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/finding_max_and_min/

Good luck and happy Map Reducing!